# AJAX, PHP & MYSQL- Limit Data Selection and Offset

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, loops

Okay so here my question i have a blog and i want to show user on first page only 5 posts so i execute this query

```
 mysql_query("select * from posts  LIMIT 5");
```

And then after showing 5 post i made a button named as: *Show more posts*

when user click on that button another PHP file(loadmoreposts.php) executed in which i execute this query

```
 mysql_query("select * from posts LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5");
```

but i want to show user 5 post every time it clicks on that button so i make this loop in my PHP script loadmoreposts.php

```
 include('dbConnectClass.php');
 $connect = new doConnect();
 $beforequery = mysql_query('select * from posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;');

if (mysql_num_rows($beforequery) > 0) {
    $max_public_id = mysql_fetch_row($beforequery);
    $lastid =  $max_public_id[0]; //Here it is
}else{
    $lastid =  "[0]";
}
echo "Last ID $lastid<br />";
    $m=5; 
    for($n=5; $n<=15; $n++): 

             $afterQuery = mysql_query("select * from posts LIMIT $m OFFSET $m");
            $m = $m+5;

            $result = "";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($afterQuery)){
            $result .= "<div class='cd-timeline-block'>";
            $result .="<div class='cd-timeline-img cd-warning'>";
            $result .=" <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i>";
            $result .="</div>";
            $result .="<div class='cd-timeline-content'>";
            $result .= "<h2>{$row['title']}</h2>
                        <p>{$row['content']}</p>
                        <img src='{$row['imagesrc']}' alt=''>
                        <br />
                        <span style='font-size:85%;'' class='label label-primary'>{$row['category']}</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>";
            }
            echo $result;
     endfor;
```

Let me explain what i did in this script, first i connect to database by a class then i grab last id of my post(last updated post) by running **$beforequery** and then one more time i execute another query named as **$afterquery** and then i get my results

but i don't want to show all my posts only in one click i want to show them 5 at a time when user click on that button like first five are already showing but clicking on button will show 5 more then after clicking again it will show the next 5 posts.
this script is then grabbed by this AJAX script:

```
var loadmoreposts = function () {
        $.post('assets/includes/fetchMoreRows.php').done(function( data ) {
            $('#displaymoreposts').html(data);
            }); 
}
```

This *loadmoreposts();* fuction is running in *onload="loadmoreposts();"body tag*

**Any Suggestions and help will be appreciated :)**

============================
   *EDITED**
   ===========================

I removed the loop and added this but not working

```
include('dbConnectClass.php');
$connect = new doConnect();


$m = $_POST['offset'];




            $afterQuery = mysql_query("select * from posts LIMIT 5 OFFSET $m");

            $result = "";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($afterQuery)){
            $result .= "<div class='cd-timeline-block'>";
            $result .="<div class='cd-timeline-img cd-warning'>";
            $result .=" <i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i>";
            $result .="</div>";
            $result .="<div class='cd-timeline-content'>";
            $result .= "<h2>{$row['title']}</h2>
                        <p>{$row['content']}</p>
                        <img src='{$row['imagesrc']}' alt=''>
                        <br />
                        <span style='font-size:85%;'' class='label label-primary'>{$row['category']}</span>
                        </div>
                        </div>" ;
            // $result .= "<tr><td> {$row['name']}</td>"."<td> {$row['password']}</td></tr></p>";
            }
            echo $result;
```

and JS/AJAX script is now this

```
   var offsetValue = 0;
   var loadmoreposts = function () {
  $.post( 'assets/includes/fetchMoreRows.php', { offset: offsetValue} ).done(function( data ) {
    $('#displaymoreposts').html(data);
    offsetValue += 5;
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about what i'm **echo**ing its not a public script and just for the admin(me) and i'm testing it, and want to make it workds :)

Comment: instead `.html()`, you could use `.append()` and pass the number of clicks to PHP

Comment: can you give me the script you are talking about by editing by script

Comment: istead of `$('#displaymoreposts').html(data);` do `$('#displaymoreposts').append(data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX script needs to send the current value for `OFFSET`, starting with `0`. Everytime you click on your `Show more posts` link, it increases the value by `5`.

So you should change your AJAX script to:

```
var offsetValue = 0;
var loadmoreposts = function () {
      $.post( 'assets/includes/fetchMoreRows.php', { offset: offsetValue} ).done(function( data ) {
        $('#displaymoreposts').html(data);
        offsetValue += 5;
      }); 
    }
```

In your PHP script, you can grab the `offset` value like that:

```
$m = $_POST['offset'];
```

Also **don't increase `LIMIT`**. Change your query to:

```
mysql_query("select * from posts LIMIT 5 OFFSET $m");
```

If you increase `LIMIT`, the script will return +5 more posts everytime.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Check my EDITED in question please

Comment: @Tayyab use this script, but i think you should use .append instead of .html

Comment: If it is not working yet, explain what is happening exactly, and try to echo out the query `$afterQuery` and check that the offset is indeed increasing with every AJAX request.

Comment: @Tayyab `echo "[$m]\n";` please. What does it say?

Comment: Thanks, it was working, unfortunately i put this function on another function(replacing) so it wasn't working...Thanks again +1

Answer (score 1):

You can simply send the offset in the AJAX request, and use that offset in your query, here are simple steps:

1. Load first 5 posts, make the value sent by AJAX "load more" button be 5
2. When "load more" button is clicked, take the value sent (in our case 5) and insert it in the query (hopefully using prepared statements for security) and retrieve next 5 posts and send back the 5 posts and the new value for "load more" button which is now 10 (can be calculated by adding 5 to the value you got from the AJAX request
3. repeat, by sending 10 when the "load more" button is clicked, retrieving next 5 posts starting at number/offset 10, returning the 5 posts and the new value for the "load more" button which is 15 (10 + 5)

and so on ...

Comment: Check my EDITED in question please and please type the script you are talking about :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

//variable to hold the offset

var offSet = 5; //initial value

//send this in your post request

```
$.post('url', {aOffset : offset }, function(returnedData) {
    // do something here

    //update the offset value
    offset+=5; });
```

Comment: Check my EDITED in question please